# How do I setup OLEDB to connect to a remote database?

Tags: database, oracle, connection, connection-string, oledb

I am locally running an Oracle 11g database. I have a small program connecting to it in code via OLEDB in VC++ (It only runs some database tests, I'm making sure I have all the basics down before I go into the real thing.)  The connection information in code only includes the provider, instance name, user name, and password.  All this aspect works fine.

```
//For example, both these ways of connecting work:
result = dataSource.Open(DATABASE_PROVIDER, DATABASE_NAME,
                         DATABASE_USER_NAME, DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD);

result = dataSource.OpenFromInitializationString(L"Provider=OraOLEDB.OracleDataSource=orcl;User ID=SYSTEM;Password=admin;");
```

I now want to send this program to other computers in my network and run it from there, connecting to my database on my local machine.
How would I go about connecting the other computers to my database in a way that the code will understand?

I have been trying to connect locally via IP instead of "localhost", figuring I could then simply use the same code and client.  In that regard, I have tried a few things without success:
-I have tried modifying the connection string to change "Data Source" to my IP, but it could not connect.
-I have tried adding some parameters from other connection string examples I had seen, but they were not for Oracle and were ignored.
-I have also tried modifying tnsnames.ora and listener.ora to change local host to an IP address, but I know that didn't work, as it would still connect if I entered rubbish.

Anyone has the knowledge to help out?

Comment: Do the other computers you are installing your code on have the Oracle client installed?  If so, which version (Instant Client, full client, etc.)?  Do these machines have tnsnames.ora entries that point to whatever database you want to connect to?

Comment: They do no have anything installed yet on the other machines, but I do expect to have to install them.  Would  modifying my tnsnames.ora in those clients solve my problem? If so, why doesn't modying tnsnames.ora locally change anything on my own machine?

Answer (score 0):

For an Oracle db, you should set up a new tnsnames entry on their individual machines that points to your local db. Then use that new tns name as the datasource. You'll also need to make sure that your local db instance is accessible to them in the first place. (This is not enabled by default in Oracle Express, by the way.)

I've also generally had more success using msdaora as the data provider instead of OraOLEDB.

Comment: In this case the use of OraOLEDB is not optional. Also, I'm not using Express, I'm using 11g Enterprise, do I still have permissions to set up?  Thanks for the reply, but there's one thing I don't understand.  If it uses tnsnames.ora to connect, how come modifying that file on my local machine doesn't, in fact, prevent me from connecting locally? Do I have to explicitly tell it to use it?